# Токен для получения данных с другого сервера

Tags: php, sql, access, token, аутентификация

На прием-сервере имеется скрипт:

```
<?php
//Прием JSON-а
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('URL'));
if (!is_array($data)) die('Json convert error');
//соединяемся с БД 
function dbConnect(){
//$cn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
$cn = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");
return $cn;
}
```

Далее тело обработки

Ждет когда с сервер-отправителя придет JSON

Как можно реализовать проверку по токену, чтобы отправитель отправлял некий ключ, а получатель до открытия сессии проверял совпадение ключа?

Comment: по тому URL и делаете в скрипте проверку токена, без него не отдаете джейсон.

Comment: Т.е. URL/$token?
А токен нужно сравнивать передаваемый и находящийся?
Или